# How to Format Business Hours of Operation from mySQL Table

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

Having looked at other questions that may already have my answer I thought to poise this question for some help. I have a template website for a bunch of business, most of which have the same start and end times - Mon. - Fri., Closed Weekends. BUT, some might close early on Friday, and be open on Saturday. I believe ALL are closed on Sunday.

I created a table as such -

```
CREATE TABLE `Shop_Hours` (
  `shop` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `d1s` time NOT NULL default '08:00:00',
  `d1e` time NOT NULL default '17:00:00',
  `d2s` time NOT NULL default '08:00:00',
  `d2e` time NOT NULL default '17:00:00',
.
.
.
  `d6s` time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  `d6e` time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  `d7s` time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  `d7e` time NOT NULL default '00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here are a few records:

```
INSERT INTO `Shop_Hours` (`shop`, `d1s`, `d1e`, `d2s`, `d2e`, `d3s`, `d3e`, `d4s`, `d4e`, `d5s`, `d5e`, `d6s`, `d6e`, `d7s`, `d7e`, `Comments`) VALUES(104, '08:00:00', '17:00:00', '08:00:00', '17:00:00', '08:00:00', '17:00:00', '08:00:00', '17:00:00', '08:00:00', '16:00:00', '08:00:00', '12:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '');
INSERT INTO `Shop_Hours` (`shop`, `d1s`, `d1e`, `d2s`, `d2e`, `d3s`, `d3e`, `d4s`, `d4e`, `d5s`, `d5e`, `d6s`, `d6e`, `d7s`, `d7e`, `Comments`) VALUES(105, '08:00:00', '17:30:00', '08:00:00', '17:30:00', '08:00:00', '17:30:00', '08:00:00', '17:30:00', '08:00:00', '17:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '');
INSERT INTO `Shop_Hours` (`shop`, `d1s`, `d1e`, `d2s`, `d2e`, `d3s`, `d3e`, `d4s`, `d4e`, `d5s`, `d5e`, `d6s`, `d6e`, `d7s`, `d7e`, `Comments`) VALUES(106, '08:30:00', '17:30:00', '08:30:00', '17:30:00', '08:30:00', '17:30:00', '08:30:00', '17:30:00', '08:30:00', '17:30:00', '08:30:00', '14:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '');
```

MY QUESTION relates to how to, using classic ASP, query a record and display as some of these examples:

Mon. - Fri. 08:00 AM - 5:00 PM

Closed Weekends

**OR**

Mon. - Th. 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM

Fri. - 8:00 AM - 4:00 PM

Sat. - 8:00 AM - 12:00 PM`

**OR**

etc...

I would think there are multiple ways to do this I am just curious to know if

- My database structure is ok?
- What is the most efficient way to get my targeted end result?

Sure would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your schema:

1. Use better variable names.  'd1s', is that Sunday or Monday?  'starttime_monday', perhaps?
2. Defaults of '00:00:00' mean 'midnight'.  Perhaps a default of NULL would be better.
3. The first thing my answer does, below, is flip your columns into rows.  You might consider storing them that way to begin with.
4. If most companies have the same hours, storing values for everyone is inefficient.  Store the exceptions only.

That said, here's a (reduced) query that works with your current schema.

Note that I'm using MySQL's values from `DAYOFWEEK`, and if you address my comments, above, the query would change.

```
select shop,
  case when hours = "12:00AM - 12:00AM" then "Closed" else hours end as hours,
  min(weekday) as minday,
  max(weekday) as maxday
from (
  select shop, "2" as weekday,
    concat(time_format(d1s,"%h:%i%p"),' - ',time_format(d1e,"%h:%i%p")) as hours
  from Shop_Hours
  union
  select shop, "3",
    concat(time_format(d2s,"%h:%i%p"),' - ',time_format(d2e,"%h:%i%p"))
  from Shop_Hours
  union
  select shop, "7",
    concat(time_format(d6s,"%h:%i%p"),' - ',time_format(d6e,"%h:%i%p"))
  from Shop_Hours
) foo
group by 1,2;
```

The output looks like this:

```
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+
| shop | hours             | minday | maxday |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|  104 | 08:00AM - 05:00PM | 2      | 3      |
|  104 | Closed            | 7      | 7      |
+------+-------------------+--------+--------+
```

Which leaves the formatting of the days to you...

Comment: WOW, this is really fantastic, thank you so very much. I am going to have to study all you provided and get back to you with some questions I am sure. Again, thanks for taking the time to help me Alain. Tom